# Incremental Totals in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in writing the SQL query for calculating the incremental totals.

For example, for the year 2015, initial value is 10 , there is change in percent on year wise. I need the total value for each year. In simple terms, for a fixed deposit of 10 with every year interest changes, what is the total accumulated value by yearwise.

```
Year  Initial Deposit    Change Percent  Change Value  Final Value  
----  -----------------  --------------  ------------  -----------
2015     Initial - 10                10           1            11              
2016               11                10           1.1          12.1              
2017               12.1               5                                       
2018                                 15                                       
2019                                 20                                      
2020                                 30                                      
2021                                  0                                      
2022                                -10                                      
2023                                 -5                                      
2024                                  1
```

In the table are calculated only first two steps.

Comment: I find this question very intersting

Comment: I was stuck in implementing logic for below formula initial_value * (1+PC1)  * (1+PC2) (1+PC3) .... (1+PCn)  which give produces the final value. But you did wonder and saved my time.  I tried SUM (1 + PC1) using OVER caluse but that logic is wrong. Note: PC -  Percent Change.

Comment: Query working good. FYI, this may not work if there is Percent change is -100 ( LOG 0 is not valid ) . I will handle this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5db5a/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table your_table(year integer, perc integer );

insert into your_table values (2015, 10);
insert into your_table values (2016,10);
insert into your_table values (2017,5);
insert into your_table values (2018,15);
insert into your_table values (2019,20);
insert into your_table values (2020,30);
insert into your_table values (2021,0);
insert into your_table values (2022,-10);
insert into your_table values (2023,-5);
insert into your_table values (2024,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH initial_value AS (
  SELECT 10 AS Initial_value FROM DUAL
)
SELECT YEAR,
       initial_value * POWER( 10, COALESCE( SUM( LOG( 10, 1+PERC/100 ) ) OVER ( ORDER BY YEAR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ), 0 ) ) AS "Initial Value",
       PERC,
       POWER( 10, COALESCE( SUM( LOG( 10, 1+PERC/100 ) ) OVER ( ORDER BY YEAR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ), 0 ) ) AS "Previous Cumulative Multiplier",
       initial_value * POWER( 10, COALESCE( SUM( LOG( 10, 1+PERC/100 ) ) OVER ( ORDER BY YEAR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ), 0 ) ) AS "Final Value"
FROM   your_table
       CROSS JOIN
       initial_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5db5a/2/0)**:

```
| YEAR | Initial Value | PERC | Previous Cumulative Multiplier |   Final Value |
|------|---------------|------|--------------------------------|---------------|
| 2015 |            10 |   10 |                              1 |            11 |
| 2016 |            11 |   10 |                            1.1 |          12.1 |
| 2017 |          12.1 |    5 |                           1.21 |        12.705 |
| 2018 |        12.705 |   15 |                         1.2705 |      14.61075 |
| 2019 |      14.61075 |   20 |                       1.461075 |       17.5329 |
| 2020 |       17.5329 |   30 |                        1.75329 |      22.79277 |
| 2021 |      22.79277 |    0 |                       2.279277 |      22.79277 |
| 2022 |      22.79277 |  -10 |                       2.279277 |     20.513493 |
| 2023 |     20.513493 |   -5 |                      2.0513493 |   19.48781835 |
| 2024 |   19.48781835 |    1 |                    1.948781835 | 19.6826965335 |
```

Comment: Very nice. But the "Previous Cumulative Multiplier" column is wrong.  Starting with the third row.

Comment: @FlorinGhita The OP is very unclear as to what is expected in the penultimate column. I read it as the cumulative multiplier applied to the starting value (at 2015) to get this year's initial value (hence my name for the column). The values in my answer are correct - for my interpretation of the OP's requirements. Your answer appears to have a different interpretation of what this column is meant to represent - the OP will need to clarify what their intent was for this column.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5db5a/7/0) also adds a column for the annual increment in the final value.

Comment: oh, sorry. Your answer is, however, just wonderfull. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a recursive CTE(Common Table Expression)

Initial load:

```
create table a(year integer, perc integer
);

insert into a values (2015, 10);
insert into a values (2016,10);
insert into a values (2017,5);
insert into a values (2018,15);
insert into a values (2019,20);
insert into a values (2020,30);
insert into a values (2021,0);
insert into a values (2022,-10);
insert into a values (2023,-5);
insert into a values (2024,1);
```

Now compute:

```
with s(year, deposit, perc, interest, final_val) as (

  select 2015 year, initial_amount, perc, 
        initial_amount*perc interest/100, 
        initial_amount*(perc+100)/100 as final_val 
  from a cross join (select 10 as initial_amount from dual)
  where year = 2015

  union all

  select a.year, s.final_val, a.perc, s.final_val*a.perc/100, s.final_val*(a.perc+100)/100
  from s join a on s.year+1 = a.year

  )
  select * from s
  ;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35814/4)

Results:

```
| YEAR |     DEPOSIT | PERC |     INTEREST |     FINAL_VAL |
|------|-------------|------|--------------|---------------|
| 2015 |          10 |   10 |            1 |            11 |
| 2016 |          11 |   10 |          1.1 |          12.1 |
| 2017 |        12.1 |    5 |        0.605 |        12.705 |
| 2018 |      12.705 |   15 |      1.90575 |      14.61075 |
| 2019 |    14.61075 |   20 |      2.92215 |       17.5329 |
| 2020 |     17.5329 |   30 |      5.25987 |      22.79277 |
| 2021 |    22.79277 |    0 |            0 |      22.79277 |
| 2022 |    22.79277 |  -10 |    -2.279277 |     20.513493 |
| 2023 |   20.513493 |   -5 |  -1.02567465 |   19.48781835 |
| 2024 | 19.48781835 |    1 | 0.1948781835 | 19.6826965335 |
```